# Where mysql writes its log seqeunce numbers and last checkpoint at?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm working on developing mysql log collecting system. 
To do that, I have to collect log sequence numbers from mysql LSN and last checkpoint location.
But I have no idea where should 
Which log file should i use to get them?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is handled in memory and transactionally stored on disk on the transaction log (by default, the `ib_logfile0` and `i_blogfile1`. But if you just want to know its value, you can check `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` or simply:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like '%lsn%';
+----------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name              | Value       |
+----------------------------+-------------+
| Innodb_lsn_current         | 25808994907 |
| Innodb_lsn_flushed         | 25808994907 |
| Innodb_lsn_last_checkpoint | 25808994907 |
+----------------------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want MySQL to output that periodically to its error log, you can [enable one of the InnoDB monitors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-enabling-monitors.html).